# What is this terminology referring to: "latlong[0].coordinates[0]"? from Google Geocoder.geocode response

Tags: python, collections, sqlite, element, google-geocoder

This how I get latitude and longitude values out of a Geocoder response from Google maps as shown:

```
latlong = Geocoder.geocode(city.find_element_by_xpath(statecol + '['  + str(statecolctr) + ']'  +  cities1 + str(statesctr) + ']' +  cities2 + '['  + str(citiesctr) + ']' + cityname).text)
```

But now I am hoping to bypass making Geocoder calls for locations that I already have the latitude and longitude from previously fetches, stored in SQLite3. I want to mimic the construct that comes from Google Geocode so that the following line of code does the exact same thing whether latlong came from Google or whether I constructed it from two string representations of latitude and longitude that I pulled in a previous Geocoder call.

```
floatlat = float(latlong[0].coordinates[0])
floatlng = float(latlong[0].coordinates[1])
```

An example of the strings that I have to start with (as stored in SQLite3) is:

```
latlong = (u'32.6098566', u'-85.4807825')
```

but from Google they look like:

```
latlong = Birmingham, AL, USA
latlong[0].coordinates[0] = 33.5206608, latlong[0].coordinates[1] = -86.80249
```

Can you help me reconstruct the first latlong above to the second, so the lat and long values are produced as shown in the second example, like they would be if latlong was the product of a Google Geocode response?  (Just the numbers, I'm not interested in the city name being a part of it)

Thank you all for your kind help that you give everyone!

Comment: Do you mean you want your ``latlong`` to have a ``coordinates`` attribute? Or do you mean you want the coordinate *values* to match, i.e. currently your ``latlong[0]`` doesn't equal Google's ``latlong[0].coordinates[0]``, but you want them to be equal?

Comment: Nevermind, I reread it and realized you want your ``latlong`` items to have a ``coordinates`` attribute. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make a class that has a `coordinates` attribute:

```
class Location(object):
    def __init__(self, lat, lng):
        self.coordinates = [lat, lng]

loc = Location(33.5206608, -86.80249)
latlong = [loc]

print(latlong[0].coordinates[0])
```

Prints: 33.5206608

Comment: I'll give that a try as soon as I gat back to things.  I do find it interesting that when I tried to do it, the error message was that my construct had no "method" coordinates while you're using the term "attribute". Either way, I'm sure this will work.  Thank you!!!!

Comment: Glad I could help. However, you should try to change your code so that it doesn't require such a specific object interface. The code I wrote above answers your question, but I don't think it's a good way of doing things.

Comment: You were right about the term 'attribute', my memory bad I see now on my screen, Thank you!

Comment: Mimicing the construct like you helped me do allows my code to be re-enterant/re-useable using the construct from either origin without ugly hacking since I have everything working already with the Google Geocode style.  Thank you!

Comment: I just did my first run, hoping I could pass the values into the new class object exactly as I retrieve them from the database (it would be nice to have it function that way). But I get the error for not having enough arguments. I retrieve both elements from the database with a single SQL command:

Comment: latlng = str(cur.fetchone()), where the SELECT I did just prior was SELECTING two columns

Comment: Tried "latlong = Coords(latlng)" and got error "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myscraper.py", line 196, in <module>
    latlong = Coords(latlng[0][1])
IndexError: string index out of range.   Tried to put indexing into it and got error:  "  File "myscraper.py", line 202, in <module>
    print 'latlong not printable directly: latlong[0].coordinates[0] = ' + str(latlong[0].coordinates[0]) +', latlong[0].coordinates[1] = ' + str(latlong[0].coordinates[1])
TypeError: 'Coords' object does not support indexing

Comment: You probably need to do ``latlong = Coords(latlng[0], latlng[1])``.

Comment: Also, don't skip this line in my answer: ``latlong = [loc]``. You need the brackets to put the location (or Coords) into a list.

Comment: I'm trying to get this "(u'32.6098566', u'-85.4807825')" to be my argument[s] for Coords to init from.  Its a single argument that I need to split into two, I'm guessing.  That's what is taking me so long here.  I'll get it pretty soon, its not that hard.